# How to change years fromd A.D to Buddhist year

Tags: php, wordpress, date, time, format

I want to change year format in my blog and post page from A.D to Buddhist year (+543)  ex: 2016 to 2559

I 've try to used plugin name  [Seed Buddhist year](https://th.wordpress.org/plugins/seed-buddhist-year/) but it's doesn't work for my theme  ( I use headwaythemes , plese someone help me)

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhubF.jpg)

Comment: Please paste the code as text into your post instead of linking to an image.

Comment: Sorry my mistake.  I found this code 

$buddhistYear = get_the_time('Y')+543;
the_time ('j F'.$buddhistYear);
the_time ('g:i a');


but I don't know how to hook in functions.php